# concatenate pandas dataframe in a loop of files

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, dataframe

I am trying to write a script that loops over files via a certain pattern/variable, then it concatenates the 8th column of the files while keeping the first 4 columns which are common to all files. The script works if I use the following command:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("1isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt", 'rU'), delimiter='\t') #to read the header names so i can use them as index. all headers for the three files are the same
header_row = reader.next() # Gets the header
df1 =  pd.read_csv("1isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt", index_col=header_row[0:4], sep="\t") #file #1 with index as first 5 columns
df2 = pd.read_csv("2isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt", index_col=header_row[0:4], sep="\t") #file #2 with index as first 5 columns
df3 = pd.read_csv("3isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt", index_col=header_row[0:4], sep="\t") #file #3 with index as first 5 columns

result = pd.concat([df1.ix[:,4], df2.ix[:,4]], keys=["Header1", "Header2", "Header3"], axis=1) #concatenates the 8th column of the files and changes the header
result.to_csv("OutputTest.xls", sep="\t")
```

While this works, it is NOT practical for me to enter file names one by one as I sometimes have 100's of files, so cant type in a df...function for each. Instead, I was trying to use a for loop to do this but i couldnt figure it out. here is what I  have so far:

```
k=0
for geneFile in glob.glob("*_tracking*"):
    while k < 3:
         reader = csv.reader(open(geneFile, 'rU'), delimiter='\t')
         header_row = reader.next()
         key = str(k)
         key = pd.read_csv(geneFile, index_col=header_row[0:1], sep="\t")
   result = pd.concat([key[:,5]], axis=1)
   result.to_csv("test2.xls", sep="\t")
```

However, this is not working .

The issues I am facing are as follows:

1. How can I be able to iterate over input files and generate different
   variable names for each which I can then have it used in the
   pd.concat function one after the other?
2. How can I use a for loop to generate a string file name that is a
   combination of `df` and an integer
3. How can I fix the above script get my desired item.
4. A minor issue is regarding the way I am using the col_index function: is there a way to use the column # rather than column names? I know it works for `index_col=0` or any single `#`. But I couldn't use integers for > 1 column of indexing.

Note that all files have the exact same structure, and the index columns are the same.

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @bioprogram, welcome to SO. Very good question. Beware of the formatting though. Clarity is very important ... :) Happy new year

Comment: If you're only ever interested in the first 4 and 8th column then just pass a list of the ordinal positions: `pd.read_csv(geneFile, index_col=header_row[0:1], sep="\t", usecols=[0,1,2,3,7])` also I think that if the index col is always the first 2 cols then you can just pass this everytime: `pd.read_csv(geneFile, index_col=[0,1], sep="\t", usecols=[0,1,2,3,7])`

Comment: Additionally you don't need to name variables, what you want to do is just append each df to a list and then at the end concat all the dfs in the list

Comment: @Andy K-thanks, I'll take notice of that in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `right_index` and `left_index` arguments:

```
import pandas as pd

numberoffiles = 100

# FIRST IMPORT (CREATE RESULT DATA FRAME)
result = pd.read_csv("1isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt", sep="\t",
                      index_col=[0,1,2,3], usecols=[0,1,2,3,7])

# ALL OTHER IMPORTS (MERGE TO RESULT DATA FRAME, 8TH COLUMN SUFFIXED ITERATIVELY)
for i in range(2,numberoffiles+1):    
    df = pd.read_csv("{}isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt".format(i), sep="\t",
                     index_col=[0,1,2,3], usecols=[0,1,2,3,7])

    result = pd.merge(result, df, right_index=True, left_index=True, suffixes=[i-1, i])

result.to_excel("Output.xlsx")
result.to_csv("Output.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. But, here are few things that i got hung at. In reality, I wanted to skip columns 2 and 3 from the output. So i wrote: result = pd.read_csv("1isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt", sep="\t", index_col=[0,3], usecols=[0,3,7]) - However, that gave an error regarding 'list index out of range' which was surprising to me as when i put usecols 0,1,2,3,7, it works. Second, I assume the {} and format(i) means that in every loop, it replaces {} with i, correct? When you set right and left index as TRUE, does this mean that it will only merge if all the indexes are the same?

Comment: Also, i really dont get what the suffixes do.I  read it on the pandas command line website and tried some examples but it did not make sense. Can you briefly explain it?

Comment: Yes to your above two questions. If you change `index_col` be sure to do it in both `pd.read_csv()` functions. Suffixes set up here basically iterates: col1, col2, col3, ... col100. I use the for loop's `i` variable to do that.

Comment: Thanks parfait. I did change it in all the pd.read_csv() and still giving the errors. I raed online that some bug is there when using index_col and usecols? is that true? very weird. I kinda find it hard to believe. I will write my whole script and see if that would work as needed. I will use your answer above as a template.

Comment: Interesting...possibly, `read_csv` expects multi-index side by side in sequence. Try leaving out the `index_col` argument and after csv import, use [set_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Comment: Yea trying that. In fact, my script didn't work when i implemented in my data structure. But it works if it is used exactly as above. The two differences I may have are: 1- My files actually are all called isoforms.fpkm_tracking.txt, but they are in different directories. Second, some values of the index column may be the same in different rows. That led the command to write the same line as same # of all the rows and messed up the structure. Aagain nevertheless, the script above works for what i asked for. perhaps i should have asked for the exact thing from the beginning. Will work on it.